# Form Data Display; insert into documents or email

Tags: email, form

I have a custom form that is not accessible to everyone, so I need a way to "copy and paste", or export to PDF, or insert form into email without losing the formatting. Also noting the form is longer than the screen so using a snipit tool will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need event receiver and create url field named like "export", and use  iTextSharp...
Note: you can use it only farm solution this can not work on sponline.